# Which design pattern is most appropriate, if any

Tags: java, design-patterns

So, this element of code has the potential to get pretty ugly. There is the potential of adding multiple elements to the list in each if statement as well as many more if/else statements. What would be the best pattern or way of going about designing this piece of code. I was thinking about the chain of responsibility but that means be passing the list round everywhere which isn't the best or even the builder pattern? Any thoughts??

```
    List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (something.contains(Effect.HARD)) {
        aList.add("");
    }

    if (something.contains(Effect.REFLECT)) {
        aList.add("");
        aList.add("");
    } else {
        aList.add("no reflect");
    }

    if (something.contains(Effect.OUTLINE)) {
        aList.add("something");
    }

    if (something.contains(Effect.GRADIENT)) {
        aList.add("gradient");
    } else {
        aList.add("no gradient");
    }
```

Comment: "... if an y"? An "y" what?

Comment: not sure how this should be put into a pattern. a pattern is created to handle events/things/... that work in the same way, it doesn't seem as if that's the case here.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please elaborate on your *real* problem? What is this code supposed to solve? If we know what actual problem you're trying to solve, it's easier for us to come up with another and possibly better solution. Right now, your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can use strategy pattern to implement switch case type of functionality where you are checking Contains , each contains have the potential to become a strategy which will keep your code clean and and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (link to wikipedia page).

Here is some lighthearted example code:

```
public interface Visilator
{
  // Process the stuff and, maybe, add an element to the kerplungy list.
  void doStuff(Stuff stuff, List<Kerplungy> kerplungyList);
}

public class Kerplungilator
{
  // Actually create this however you choose.
  @Autowired
  private List<Visilator> visilatorList;

  public List<Kerplungy> processStuffs(final Stuff stuff)
  {
    final List<Kerplungy> returnValue = LinkedList<>(); // ArrayList is for chumps.

    for (final Visilator current : visilatorList)
    {
      current.doStuff(Stuff, returnValue);
    }

    return returnValue;
  }
}

public clss HootVisilator
implements Visilator
{
  public void doStuff(
    @NotNull final Stuff stuff,
    @NotNull final List<Kerplungy> kerplungyList)
  {
    if (stuff.hoot())
    {
      final Kerplungy hootKerplungy = new Kerplungy("hoot");

      kerplungyList.add(hootkerplungy);
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("not hoot");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd look at replacing those ugly conditionals with polymorphic code, but that won't work well here as the conditions (`something.contains(...)`) are not based on the type of the object. You could turn them into objects, but this would not be an elegant solution either. Builder and Visitor could be used, but I doubt very much you code would more readable at all.